# How do I know which exception occurred when my app crashed?

Tags: node.js, express, logging

I am working on a NodeJS module, and I have the following problem:

When some error occurs in the promise chain, I can handle the exception, log it to my centralized logging tool, and all is well.

However, from time to time I see some errors that right out crash the application, and it restarts leaving me with nothing to go on. Only when I look into the logs in the machine that I can figure out what is going on. The latest one was this:

`TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

How can I log the error that crashes the application to a centralized log tool. I understand that if the app died it can't do anything. But there must be a strategy to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to handle the exception is to create one helper function where you must configure with error logging tool like (rollbar in heroku), and in every function/routes, you must include your source code inside the try-catch block. 
Write your code inside the try section and use the helper function and pass the exception to the helper file. It will look like this

```
//helper.js

const handleException = (exception) => {
//configure your error logging tool here.
}
const internalServerError = env => (err, req, res, next) => {
  if (!err) {
    return next();
  }
  handleException(err)//utilize common handler
};

module.exports = { handleException }
```

and in the main file

```
//app.js
const { handleException, internalServerError } = required('helper');
app.post((req, res) => {
   try {
      //your code will goes here
   } catch(err) {
     handleException(err)//you can customize error as per requirements
   }
});

//uncatch exception will trigger here. Put this bottom of the routes file. 
 app.use(internalServerError());
```

Comment: Hmm. I see. this makes a lot of sense, will this also catch errors that crash the app like in my original post?

Comment: you can handle such kind of exception via app.use(internalServerError()); is already given above.

Answer (score 0):

Place inside try/catch block any expression that might generate an error . Handle the error there or forward it with new information attached.

```
try {

   suspectedFunction()
}
catch(e) {

   logError(e)

   if (necessary){
     e.parseSuccess = false;
     throw e
   }

}
```

Comment: All my endpoints are inside a promise chain structure. shouldn't that have a built-in try/catch ?

Comment: There is no reason why Node should just exit if all your statements are handled well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a logging library such as Winston with the express-winston module [express-winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-winston)  this provides error logging middleware, for example:

```
  var express = require('express');
  var expressWinston = require('express-winston');
  var winston = require('winston');
  var app = express();

  app.use(expressWinston.logger({
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'express.log' })
      ],
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.json()
      )
  }));

  app.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
      res.send('All good');
  });

  app.get('/error', function(req, res, next) {
      // Let's cause an error.
      let r = JSON.stringify(req);
  });

  app.listen(3000, function(){
      console.log(`Express Listening on port ${this.address().port}`);
  });

  app.use(expressWinston.errorLogger({
      transports: [
          new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'express-error.log' })
      ],
      format: winston.format.combine(
          winston.format.json()
      )
  }));
```